# Using mathematical operators in MSBuild properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

The goal of this is to set the build version to be a timestamp of the build date.  I use a `Directory.Build.props` file to set project properties, in which I have the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Month).$([System.DateTime]::Now.Day).$([System.DateTime]::Now.Year)</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works perfectly fine, but I would like to increase the resolution of the timestamp, by adding the total seconds elapsed in the day.

I can get this value fairly easily by doing `$([System.DateTime]::Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds)`, but this is a Double and the Version needs a UInt16 - 1.

I *think* I can convert to a UInt16 by doing `$([System.Convert]::ToUInt16( theAboveExpression ))`.

However, the double can be too large, so I need to divide it first, and I can't figure out how to do this at all.  My best attempt so far amounts to blind flailing since I can't seem to find any examples of this:

`$( $([System.DateTime]::Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds) / 2 )`

This expression cannot be evaluated, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: This is a very unusual versioning regime, just saying. Going with this approach makes it look like every month you get a major upgrade, then a down grade every year  :/ personally this looks very troublesome

Comment: @MichaelRandall I am aware that this is odd.  It makes (more) sense given the situation.  And even if it didn't make sense, I would like to learn how to do this - avoiding problems doesn't exactly lead to improvement.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, i wasn't criticising or trying to be unhelpful, just giving you a professional opinion in case you hadn't seen the ramifications.

Comment: MSBuild has some [built in methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019#msbuild-property-functions) you can use for calculations

Comment: @SimplyGed Yeah, looks like I posted my answer where I figured that out just before your comment.  Thank you though!

Comment: @Aze, you can also accept your answer and mark as resolved

Comment: @Clint Yes, after I wait my 48 hours out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, shortly after deciding to ask for help I figure it out...

MSBuild includes [MSBuild Property Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019), which can be used to divide things and perform other operations.  Here is an example of working code that does as I needed:

```
<Version>
  $([System.DateTime]::Now.Month).
  $([System.DateTime]::Now.Day).
  $([System.DateTime]::Now.Year).
  $([System.Convert]::ToUInt16(
      $([MSBuild]::Divide(
          $([System.DateTime]::Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds),
          2
      ))
  ))
</Version>
```

Comment: Also note that if you use a different scale, you can better map the 0..86400 to 0..65535. I use `$([System.Convert]::ToUInt16($([MSBuild]::Multiply($([System.DateTime]::Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds), $([MSBuild]::Divide(65535, 86400))))))`, which gives me about 50% more version numbers. I calculate the scale directly, to avoid dealing with cultures and parsing of decimal numbers.